# Missing parenthesis error oracle ORA-00907

Tags: compiler-errors, oracle10g, ora-00907

I want to execute this procedure with the following input parameters.

```
DECLARE 
    in_fieldname_list VARCHAR2(4000); 
    L_FILE_NAME VARCHAR(200); 


    BEGIN 

    in_fieldname_list := 'PROPTYPE'', ''ADDR1'', ''CITY'', ''STATE'', ''ZIP'', ''OAPPRAISAL'; 

    pack_audit_trail_report.SP_AUDIT_TRAIL ( 
        'B', 
        'LEH005', 
        NULL, 
        NULL, 
       in_fieldname_list, 
        '12/10/2012', 
        '01/15/2013', 
        L_FILE_NAME); 
    END;
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Error report:
: missing right parenthesis
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_SQL", line 909
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SQL", line 39
ORA-06512: at "CDM.PACK_AUDIT_TRAIL_REPORT", line 166
ORA-06512: at line 10
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Please let me know where am I missing the parenthesis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know, what your `SP_AUDIT_TRAIL` procedure requires, but I feel you should feed it field list with correct number of quotes:

```
in_fieldname_list := '''PROPTYPE'', ''ADDR1'', ''CITY'', ''STATE'', ''ZIP'', ''OAPPRAISAL''';
```

Comment: Using the q operator makes this IMHO slightly more readable: q'|'PROPTYPE', 'ADDR1', 'CITY', 'STATE', 'ZIP', 'OAPPRAISAL'|'